# Cast integer to string - rails - mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, casting

I'm trying to cast an integer as a string in a rails query.  For example, I want to replicate this SQL

```
SELECT CAST(id AS CHAR) FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`name` = 'Frustrated';
```

This selects the id

```
Article.where( name: "Frustrated" ).select("id")
```

But this dies

```
 Article.where( name: "Frustrated" ).select("CAST (id AS CHAR) ")
```

even though the SQL looks identical.

Is it possible to do this, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was only spaces in the wrong place.  This works

```
Article.where( name: "Frustrated" ).select("CAST(id AS CHAR)")
```