# How to query with cast?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activeadmin

I'm building a Rails app have a model `User`, which has many `Telephone`s, and each `Telephone` `has_many :active_admin_comments, foreign_key: "resource_id", class_name: 'ActiveAdmin::Comment'`

Resource id is a string.

Now I would like to list all the Users, their Telephones and Comments in ActiveAdmin.

```
panel "Telephones" do
  table_for User
    .joins({event: :active_admin_comments}) do |t|
      t.column('User:') {|res| res}
    end
  end
```

But I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer LINE 1: ...omments" ON "active_admin_comments"."resource_id" = "telephones"... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users" ON "telephones"."id" = "users"."telephone_id" INNER JOIN "active_admin_comments" ON "active_admin_comments"."resource_id" = "telephones"."id"
```

It might be because `resource_id` is a string and `telephone.id` is an integer.

I tried to make a raw query but got the same result.

How do I make this query properly?

====

Edit 1:

I tried this and I don't get an error

```
query = 'SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users" ON "telephones"."id" = "users"."telephone_id" INNER JOIN "active_admin_comments" ON "active_admin_comments"."resource_id" = CAST("telephones"."id" AS varchar)'
hi = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
hi.each do |t|
  puts t
end
```

It prints:

`{"id"=>"14488", "created_at"=>"2019-06-18 07:49:48.749594", "updated_at"=>"2019-06-18 07:49:48.79131", "telephone_id"=>"12518"}`

If I try `puts t.active_admin_comments` I get: `undefined method`active_admin_comments' for #`

Comment: Why is resource_id a string, if it is telephone's foreign_key?

Comment: @LucasWieloch I'm dealing with the legacy code and I can't change this, but it actually might come from ActiveAdmin::Comment directly.

Comment: Which Rails version are you using? I think I know how you can solve this in an 'elegant' way if it's > 4.4

Comment: I use 4.1.8, maybe it will still work

Comment: In your question you have a block that you were able to make the correct query (in the **Edit 1** section). Have you tried that query using Rails [scopes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)?

I have had a quite similar problem in the past and I used scopes to solve it. I'm a bit busy this month so it'll take a long time for me to write a proper answer, sorry.

Comment: In case you are having trouble using CAST within your Ruby query, you might want to take a look at this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930846/cast-integer-to-string-rails-mysql